# Borel-Cantelli (?) to show that a lim sup inequality of rapid decay random variables holds with prob. 1

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

A random variable $\xi$ in probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ is said to have $c$-rapid decay if $P(\xi > k)\leq e^{-ck}$ for sufficiently large $k$. I'm given a sequence $\xi_n$ of random variables of $c$-rapid decay in $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$, so $$P(\xi_n>k(n))\leq e^{-ck(n)} \ \ (*)$$ for large enough $k(n)$, and I'm asked to **show that** $$\limsup \frac{\xi_n(\omega)}{\log n}\leq \frac{1}{c} \quad \textrm{with probability 1}.$$ My thoughts are these: $$\{\omega\in\Omega \ | \ \limsup \frac{\xi_n(\omega)}{\log n} > \frac{1}{c}\}=\bigcup_{M\in\mathbb{N}}\{\omega\in\Omega \ | \ \xi_n(\omega)/\log n > 1/c + 1/M \ \textrm{infinitely often}\}$$ so fix $M$ and define $$E_n=\{\omega\in\Omega \ | \ \xi_n(\omega)/ \log n > H:= 1/c + 1/M\}.$$ In order to apply Borel-Cantelli I need to estimate $P(E_n)$ and evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(E_n)$, using the given hypothesis $(*)$. This is where I'm stuck.

Is my approach correct? How do I finish it? Thank you.

Comment: Is $k(n)$ just any increasing sequence?

Comment: @Rookatu I don't think it's necessarily increasing. $\xi$ is said to have $c$-rapid decay if $P(\xi > k)\leq e^{-ck}$ for sufficiently large $k$. Each $\xi_n$ is of $c$-rapid decay here.

Comment: Without estimates on $k(n)$, this is undoable (and the result is then wrong, btw).

Comment: @Did So I suspected. Perhaps I'm misinterpreting what that inequality "with probability 1" means? How do you think the statement should be modified? But, more importantly, could you please tell me what the counterexample is?

Comment: $\xi_n=n$ with full probability.

Comment: @Did Indeed. Thanks. Other than that, are there any mistakes in what I wrote?